# Uniform convergence and negating uniform convergence in logical symbols

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

How do you write this in logical symbols:
For each $\epsilon>0$ there exist a number $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in S$ and all $n>N$.

Is this correct? 
$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N,(x\in S\land n>N\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon)$

And how can I negate this?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s

$$\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists N\in\Bbb N\,\forall x\in S\,\forall n>N\big(|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\big)\;;$$

its negation, after the negation is pulled inside all the quantifiers, is

$$\exists\epsilon>0\,\forall N\in\Bbb N\,\exists x\in S\,\exists n>N\big(|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge\epsilon\big)\;.$$

This negation can be performed mechanically, using the equivalence of $\neg\forall x\varphi(x)$ with $\exists x\neg\varphi(x)$ and the equivalence of $\neg\exists x\varphi(x)$ with $\forall x\neg\varphi(x)$.

Informally, the negation says that there is a ‘bad’ $\epsilon$, meaning one such that no matter how far out in the sequence $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ you go, you can find an $n$ at least that far out and a point $x\in S$ such that $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ differ by at least $\epsilon$.

Comment: Is $\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists N\in\Bbb N\,\forall x\in S\,\forall n>N\big(|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\big)\;$ equivalent with $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N,(x\in S\land n>N\implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon)$ ?

Comment: @Kasper: My version contains a little more information, in that it explicitly specifies that $N\in\Bbb N$, but otherwise theyre equivalent. I would omit the comma from yours, however: it serves only to clutter up the expression, since it adds nothing to the information conveyed by the parentheses.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @Kasper: You’re welcome!

Comment: Can't I pull out "$\forall N\in\Bbb N,\exists n>N$" from the negation and replace it (in the position where $\forall N\in\Bbb N$ was) with "$\forall n\in\Bbb N$"? They seem equivalent to me.

Comment: @Ryan: No, they’re not equivalent. Consider a simpler example: $$\forall N\in\Bbb N\exists n>N(n\text{ is even})$$ is true, but $$\forall n\in\Bbb N(n\text{ is even})$$ is false.

Comment: Ah thanks! I've been using the condensation "$\forall n \in \mathbb N$" to prove that the pointwise convergence isn't uniform (this is valid), and hadn't realised that the converse isn't true.